# How can I read a text file and display it using JoptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, ioexception, java-io

I am trying to take in user input and storing it in a text file, I was able to take in the input and storing it but now i am trying to display that input in a `JOptionPane` window. Can someone please help me. I am new on stackflow and this is my first post.

```
/*Here i am taking in user input and storing it in a file called "dictionary.txt".*/
public static String addNewWord()throws IOException
{
    String newWord = "";

    newWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the word you want to add to your dictionary.");

    FileWriter aDictionary = new FileWriter("dictionary.txt", true);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aDictionary);
    out.println(newWord);
    out.close();
    aDictionary.close();

    return newWord;
}
/* Now i am trying to read "dictionary.txt" and display it using JOptionPane*/
public static String listDictionary()throws IOException
{
   FileReader aDictionary = new FileReader("dictionary.txt");
   String aLineFromFile = FileReader;
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, aLineFromFile);
   aDictionary.close();

   return aLineFromFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `BufferedReader` to read the data back from the file:

```
public static void listDictionary()throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));
    String aLineFromFile = null;
    while ((aLineFromFile = br.readLine()) != null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, aLineFromFile);
    }        
    br.close();
    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks, and if its multiple lines how would i do that? currently it only reads one line of the text file.

Comment: i have updated the code to reflect reading multiple lines, and incidently I don't think you want to return a string from this function. I have removed that as well